# Javascript unable to remove class in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Currently working with [Zurb Foundation's Clearing Lightbox plugin](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html) and using a `block-grid` class on a `ul` element. Trying to remove the `small-block-grid-2` and `medium-block-grid-3` classes from `.carousel > ul`

HTML Generated

```
<div id="gallery">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <div class="clearing-assembled">
                    <div class="">
                        <a class="clearing-close" href="#">×</a>

                        <div class="visible-img" style="display: none;">
                            <img src="/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"
                            style=
                            "visibility: visible; margin-left: -150px; margin-top: -100.5px;">

                            <p class="clearing-caption" style="display: none;">
                            </p><a class="clearing-main-prev disabled" href=
                            "#"></a><a class="clearing-main-next" href="#"></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="carousel">
                            <ul class=
                            "small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 clearing-thumbs"
                            data-clearing="" style="">
                                <li class="visible"><a href=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"><img alt="Customer1"
                                src=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"></a></li>

                                <li><a href=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"><img alt="Customer1"
                                src=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"></a></li>

                                <li><a href=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"><img alt="Customer1"
                                src=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"></a></li>

                                <li><a href=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"><img alt="Customer1"
                                src=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"></a></li>

                                <li><a href=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"><img alt="Customer1"
                                src=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"></a></li>

                                <li><a href=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"><img alt="Customer1"
                                src=
                                "/assets/home/our-customers/customer1.jpg"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CoffeeScript

```
display = $(".carousel").siblings(".visible-img").css("display")                                                             
unless display  == "none"                                                                                                    
    $("#gallery .carousel > ul").removeClass("small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3")
```

I'm think the problem is with the conditional passing. When an image is clicked, the `display: none` style is changed to either `display: block` or `style=`

**Update**

I've just tried to load only
`('.carousel > ul').removeClass('small-block-grid-2');`, but it doesn't load. I think the issue is with the actual javascript file being loaded and the rails asset pipeline.

**Final Update**
Changed the original question to reflect what I found to be the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is a little different from what I was asking, but I was able to fix it by fixing the Ruby on Rails asset pipeline's javascript loading order.

**Before** `application.js`

```
//= require jquery                                                                                                           
//= require jquery_ujs                                                                                                       
//= require placeholder                                                                                                      
//= require foundation                                                                                                       
//= require turbolinks                                                                                                       
//= require_tree .
```

**After** `application.js`

```
//= require jquery                                                                                                           
//= require jquery_ujs                                                                                                       
//= require placeholder                                                                                                      
//= require foundation                                                                                                       
//= require turbolinks                                                                                                       
//= require_self                                                                                                             
//= require_tree .
```

The difference is `//= require_self`. What this does is require the content of the `application.js` in the order I want the javascript files to load in. After the `//= require_self` I added `//= require_tree .` to include all the other javascript files I have in the same directory.

The problem was that I was loading a specific javascript file before the `application.js` was loaded.

Final `cars.js.coffee`

```
$(document).ready ->                                                                                                         
  $("#gallery .carousel > ul a").click ->                                                                                    
    $("#gallery .carousel > ul").removeClass "small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3"                                        

  $("#gallery .clearing-close").click ->                                                                                     
    $("#gallery .carousel > ul").addClass "small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3"
```